# Book on probability theory which is comprehensive and covers covariance, conditional probability and probability distributions, all with proofs?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, book-recommendation, conditional-probability

My background is in Computer Science and I'd like to establish a strong foundation in probability theory.

I was reading the GraphSLAM paper to get a sense of the algorithms used for SLAM purposes in robots. While reading it, I realized that I have a tenuous grasp on probability theory, especially on topics like covariance, conditional probability and multivariate distributions (even things like posterior probability confuse me). I've tried to search online for explanations but haven't found a single source which is both complete and comprehensive in its take. This has led to a state where I know things by name, but hardly understand them.

I'd like to rectify this and gain an intuitive understanding of the subject, since it is commonly used in numerous areas of engineering.

I dislike books that introduce fully formed theorems with no derivation or proof of how they came into existence. Which comprehensive book(s) can I read?

Comment: You say you want a strong foundation in probability theory, but I think you just want a more computational approach. A strong foundation requires real analysis, measure theory, and even some areas of topology, which I don’t think you’re interested in. Are you?

Comment: I wouldn't say that I just want a computational approach. What I mean by strong foundation is that I want to have an intuitive understanding of the underlying concepts. I want to know how gaussian distribution came into existence and why is it so popularly used and what are the caveats of using it, and not just what is the formula for its PDF. I have little to almost no formal knowledge of measure theory and topology. Do you think I should start with those?

Answer (score 0):

The book **Sheldon M Ross: A First course in Probability (9th ed), Pearson (2013)** seems to suit your needs.
 It is highly recommended by Premium Educational Institutions for those having interest in Data Science, or having a background in Computer Science. It does have enough material to build your background as well as application-based part demanded in Computer Science.

Find it [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032179477X).
You may also find [this](https://www.ctanujit.org/uploads/2/5/3/9/25393293/_introduction_to_probability_models_by_ross_sheldon.pdf) helpful, the pdf of **Introduction to Probability Models by Sheldon Ross.**